# Coding issue with clang-format on Windows

Tags: character-encoding

After a recent Emacs update, the clang-format package started to misbehave under Windows. For instance, calling `clang-format-buffer` on a `test.cpp` file with the following content returns error:

```
"(clang-format failed with code 1: error: invalid length 34, offset + length (34) is outside the file.)"


{
  int a = 2;
  int b = 1;
}
```

It seems that the length passed to `clang-format` is right, because putting Point at the end of the buffer and calling `(bufferpos-to-filepos (point))` returns `34`. The file uses DOS-style file endings. But the error seems to be that `call-process-region` passes `\n` line endings to clang-format instead of `\r\n`.

The documentation of [`clang-process-region`](https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/elisp-manual-21-2.8/html_node/elisp_604.html) states:

> The input sent to a subprocess by call-process-region is encoded using a coding system, much like text written into a file.

`buffer-file-coding-system` in the buffer is `undecided-dos`. Is it normal then that `call-process-region` passes `\n` instead or `\r\n` to clang-format?

The clang-format package I tried is installed from melpa.org, version **20161004.253**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue comes from the fact Emacs using `undecided-unix` by default for sending data to a subprocess. Calling `describe-coding-system` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>h</kbd>, <kbd>C</kbd>) shows all the different encodings used for a given buffer.

This issue is fixed by calling `(setq default-process-coding-system '(undecided-dos . undecided-dos))`

I've filed a bug report on llvm.org's bug tracker to see if this can be solved in clang-format.el directly. https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=31092